# How to pass a variable returned from evaluate to another evaluate in Nightmare.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I'm currently trying to extract data of a table using Nightmare.js with vo. The table that I'm trying to extract have multiple page and I have to extract the entirety of that table into an outerHTML string which will be turned into JSON later. The code that I'm using is running through a loop which each contain an evaluate() function. What I want to do is to have a variable keeping the data I want to extract (String) and add new data to it with each loop. However, I encounter a problem when I couldn't send a variable from the previous evaluate() to the next. Here's the run function of my code.

```
function *run() {
  var totalPageNumber = "";
  var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });
  yield nightmare
    .goto('https://www.svgame168.com/IGKiosk/guest/login.aspx')
    .select('#ctl00_ddlLanguage', 'th-TH')
    .wait(3000)
    .insert('input[name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$UserName"]', userName)
    .insert('input[name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$Password"]', password)
    .click('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_LoginButton')
    .wait(3000)
    .goto('https://www.svgame168.com/IGKiosk/playermgt/Default.aspx')
    .click('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_searchBtn')
    .wait(6000)
    .evaluate(function () {
      var result = "";
      var nextPageExist = document.evaluate("//a[contains(., '>')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
      nextPageExist = nextPageExist.iterateNext();result = document.querySelector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dataGridView").outerHTML;
      var totalPageNumber = document.querySelector("#main_content_table > tbody > tr > td > table:nth-child(5) > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > div:nth-child(4) > span > div:nth-child(1)");

      if (nextPageExist != null){
        nextPageExist.className += " nextPageExist1";
      }
      return totalPageNumber;
    })

  for (var i = 2; i <= 11; i++) {
    console.log("Currently on page " + i);
    yield nightmare
      .click(".nextPageExist" + (i - 1))
      .wait(6000)
      .evaluate(function (result) {
        var nextPageExist = document.evaluate("//a[text()='>']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
        nextPageExist = nextPageExist.iterateNext();

        console.log(result);
        result += document.querySelector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dataGridView").outerHTML;
        //console.log(result);
        if (nextPageExist != null){
          var pageNumber = document.querySelector("#main_content_table > tbody > tr > td > table:nth-child(5) > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > div:nth-child(4) > span > div:nth-child(2) > span").innerHTML
          pageNumber = pageNumber.replace(/\D/g,'');
          nextPageExist.className += " nextPageExist" + pageNumber;
        }
        return result
      })
  }
  yield nightmare
    .end()
    .then(function (result) {
      console.log(tabletojson.convert(result));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error('Search failed:', error);
    });
}
```

I suspect that my syntax when I receive variable in the second evaluate is wrong but I couldn't find the solution. I tried using this and it'd still give an error.

```
      .evaluate(function (result) {
        var nextPageExist = document.evaluate("//a[text()='>']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
        nextPageExist = nextPageExist.iterateNext();

        console.log(result);
        result += document.querySelector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dataGridView").outerHTML;
        //console.log(result);
        if (nextPageExist != null){
          var pageNumber = document.querySelector("#main_content_table > tbody > tr > td > table:nth-child(5) > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > div:nth-child(4) > span > div:nth-child(2) > span").innerHTML
          pageNumber = pageNumber.replace(/\D/g,'');
          nextPageExist.className += " nextPageExist" + pageNumber;
        }
        return result
      }, result)
```

The above code works if I remove 'result' variable from every line in evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the way to return the result from the evaluate method and store it and to move to the next page

```
return nightmare
        .click(".nextPageExist" + (i - 1))
        .wait(5000) // wait till the page is loaded
        .evaluate(() => {
           //extract data from table
           //return the data
           return result
         })
        .then((result) => {
           //recieve the data from previous step 
           
           //add the result to an global array
           tableResults.push(result);

         })
```

the above code can iterate inside an array reducer like below, using reducer is much more recommended that using a for loop.

```
let pages = [1, 2, 3, 4] // assuming there are 4 pages, create an array with a 
                         //length of 4

pages.reduce(accumulator, currentValue, index, arr)
{
      accumulator.then(() => {
         return nightmare
        .click(".nextPageExist" + (currentValue - 1))
        .wait(5000) // wait till the page is loaded
        .evaluate(() => {
           //extract data from table
           //return the data
           return result
         })
        .then((result) => {
           //recieve the data from previous step 
           
           //add the result to an global array
           tableResults.push(result);

         })
      })
    

}, Promise.resolve());
```